# how to use argument on discord.js that already setted a command handler

Tags: javascript

how I can use an argument on discord.java that has a command handler? is there any code for an argument for the command handler? I don't know what to put because I'm new at java, and I don't know all the java code function, and when I try this code

```
const { Message } = require("discord.js")

exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
    message.channel.send('Test Confirmed!');
};
```

the argument doesn't work, I have tried to enter the command (kl-test) but nothing happens, so is there any argument code for the command handler?

Comment: That is not java, that is javascript. Moreover, what you want is not clear.

Comment: i know, but, its grammar..... block maybe..... when i tried to post the question its have some grammar block, and the "javascript" word have red line, so i think its grammar block so i change "javascript"word to "java"